# How to make Qt icon (in menu bar and tool bar) larger?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I think the default size is too small. Any way to change it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user1899020 , your question is very interesting. I'm trying to do the same. Unfortunately, I still do not find a clear answer on how to actually do it. Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `QToolbar` has `iconSize` property.
2. As far as I know, the only way to change `QMenu` icon size is to create a custom style for it. You can read about it [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15742-How-to-change-Icon-size-in-QMenu)

Comment: I agree with this statement: `the only way to change QMenu icon size is to create a custom style for it`. I've clicked on your link, but cannot find a clear explanation on how to actually do it. @hank : Please help..